# How to handle character "#" in Regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying the code below:

```
String txt = "D D#";
String txt2 = txt.replaceAll("\\bD\\b", "x").replaceAll("\\bD#\\b", "y");
```

I'm waiting to get `"x y"`, but it returns `"x x#"`. What could be the solution?

Comment: Here is what happens: "D D#" -> "x x#" -> "x #x" ... so you need to start with replacing "D#".

Comment: At the time you're calling the 2nd `replaceAll()`, all your D's are replaced by x's. Try `.replaceAll("x#", "y");`

Comment: Call `.replace("D#", "y")` first then call `.replace("D", "x")`. There is no need to use `replaceAll` as you're not using regex here.

Comment: @anubhava Edited!

Comment: Then use: `.replaceAll("\\bD#", "y").replaceAll("\\bD\\b", "x")` You cannot use `\\b` after `#` since it is not a word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your edited question, you want to do replacements with word boundaries.

You may use this code to fix:

```
String txt = "D D#";
String txt2 = txt.replaceAll("\\bD#", "y").replaceAll("\\bD\\b", "x");
//=> "x y"
```

Note the changes:

1. Calling `.replaceAll("\\bD#", "y")` before other `replaceAll` that is replacing all words with `D` with `x`.
2. Not using word boundary `\\b` after `#` since word boundary is not matched after a non-word character. `\b` is asserted for `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` positions.

Also note that you can also use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll` and keep code as:

```
String txt2 = txt.replaceFirst("\\bD\\b", "x").replaceFirst("\\bD#", "y");
```

Comment: It just answered! Thanks!
Could you elaborate on replaceFirst() a little more?

Comment: `replaceFirst` replaces only first matched text in input.